# How to Manage Unicode Characters in Powershell

Tags: powershell, unicode

I have created a powershell script which execute an external command.

```
$filenames = command.exe $remoteFolder
```

this command returns a list of filenames, but in Unicode, filenames are then stored in an output CSV file

```
"$remoteFolder;$filename" >> $exportFile
```

Unfortunately output file does not show correctly accent letters

```
file├á.txt
```

what is the best way to have the accent letters show correclty?

Thanks.

Comment: What psversion do you use?

Comment: Use `... |Add-Content $exportFile` instead of `... >> $exportFile`

Comment: It's a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case of the following kind (example in Python): `'├á'.encode('cp850').decode('utf-8')` returns `'à'`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how to pass encoding to `Out-File` commandlet:

```
if ($PSVersionTable.PSEdition -eq "Core")
{
    $MyEncoding = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.UTF8Encoding -ArgumentList $false
}
else
{
    $MyEncoding = "utf8"
}

"$remoteFolder\$filename" | Out-File -Encoding $MyEncoding -FilePath "MyUnicodeFile.txt"
```

You change encoding to something else if UTF8 doesn't give expected results.

Answer (score 0):

`>>` doesn't check the encoding of the output file before appending utf16/unicode characters to it, so it may mix different encodings.  I would pipe to add-content instead.  The file would have to be utf8 or utf16 in the first place.  There might be a problem with an external command outputting unicode characters as well.  It would be helpful to know what the unicode characters and the external command are.

```
"$remoteFolder;$filename" | add-content $exportFile
```